# I am getting an error when i run twine upload

Tags: python, pip, pypi, twine

I ran this command:

`twine upload ./*`

and this error happened:

```
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
ERROR    InvalidDistribution: Unknown distribution format:  
         'dist'
```

edit: I forgot to run it in the dist folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what does `./*` expand to? Chances are you've built your packages one way or another, and you now have a `dist/*` directory with the package files, so the correct incantation would be

```
twine upload dist/*
```

to upload the one or two files in `dist/`.